# Using Map in Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, dictionary, coffeescript, hashmap

I'm not sure what kind of map functionality javascript/coffeescript has, but suppose I convert a Java map to an appropriate format, can i use coffeescript to do something like

```
thekey.getValue()
```

where getValue will be a function defined in my coffeescript that will do do the equivalent of

```
 return MyMap.get(key)   (returns value)
```

edit: I had a java tag because its not obvious to me depending on what I need to do how to convert the map from java to javascript

Edit: would something like this work?

```
click: ->
 if Object1.label in Object2
      $("#multiValueSelect").val(Object2[Object1.label].toLowerCase()).trigger "change"
 else
      $("#multiValueSelect").val(Object1.label.toLowerCase()).trigger "change"
```

Comment: Yes, that should work. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript's fundamental `Object` type is essentially a Map as it is. In both JavaScript and CoffeeScript `myObject.value` will get you the property named `value` out of `myObject`. To get a property using a string key, use square brackets: `myObject[key]`.

Comment: so suppose i have a map (in this case object) object1 which is string to integer and object2 that is string to string. Then suppose I have a key (object1.label) and I want to get the value from Object2, I would do Object2.Object1.label and that would give me the string value from object2 using object1 as the key?

Comment: sorry if that was unclear please ask for clarification if it is

Comment: In that case you want `Object2[Object1.label]`. Also note FYI JavaScript objects can ONLY hold strings as keys, so in that way they are limited in comparison to Java Maps.

Comment: ok also as a followup right now i have click: -> $("#multiValueSelect").val(o.label.toLowerCase()).trigger "change", so what i want to do is if the label is present in object2 use the corresponding string and if not use the default label

Comment: so i would do something like if Object1.label in Object2  Object2[Object1.label] else object1.label?

Comment: @Lemonio: You can use backticks in your comments for formatting, trying to separate the code from the text is difficult without a bit of formatting.

Comment: ah sweet i didn't know that, i also made an edit in my post though

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define a map and use it in javascript like

```
var map = {}; (or you give it appropriate value)    
return map[key]; (or map.key)
```

in coffeescript:

```
map = {}
map[key] (or map.key)
```